# How to check all children based on parent while also checking parent based on children?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-checked

Plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/Tt96EE2rruy1HAudRVJR?p=preview

I have the following nested loops of checkboxes:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="continent in destinations">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="continent.selected">
    {{continent.name}} ({{continent.countries_selected}} / {{continent.countries.length}}) - {{continent.all_selected}}
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="country in continent.countries">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="country.selected" ng-checked="continent.selected">
        {{country.name}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And this is the code that detects ($watch) whether some or all children checkboxes have been checked, if so, parent checkbox gets checked as well.

That works fine.

But, when I check the parent box, it doesn't check.

What I want to achieve is that when I check a parent checkbox, all its children get checked as well and when I uncheck the parent checkbox, all its children get unchecked.

```
$scope.$watch('destinations', function(destinations){

  var total_selected = 0;

  angular.forEach(destinations, function(continent){

    continent.countries_selected = 0;

    angular.forEach(continent.countries, function(country){

      total_selected += country.selected ? 1 : 0

      continent.countries_selected += country.selected ? 1 : 0

      if (continent.countries_selected == continent.countries.length) {
        continent.selected = true;
      } else {
        continent.selected = false;
      }

    });

  });

  $scope.select_all = function(continent){
    continent.selected = true;
  }

  $scope.total_selected = total_selected;

}, true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try it . call a `function` on change of `continent` value

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="continent.selected" ng-change="parentChange($index)">
```

and in controller: add another function

```
$scope.parentChange = function(index) {
    angular.forEach( $scope.destinations[index].countries, function(country) {
      country.selected = $scope.destinations[index].selected;
    });
  };
```

and may be no need to add `ng-checked="continent.selected"` for country checkbox.

use

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="country.selected">
```

instead of

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="country.selected" ng-checked="continent.selected">
```

[Plunker DEMO LINK](https://plnkr.co/edit/sQfA2UL5dRC601R1QQul?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

The ng-checked attribute in the checkbox takes in an expression. So you can give an expression with and/or conditions, as mentioned below to make it checked based on an expression.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="child_1 && child_2 && child_3 && child_4 && child_5" ng-model="parent"/> Select All<br/>
```

You dont have to write a seprate function to do the computation when every child checkbox is clicked

[Here is the example](http://jsfiddle.net/pio123/624y6/1/)